# Query Where equal to range of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I want to set up a Query in Google Sheets and want to use cell content as a condition.

Is it possible to do sth. like `"SELECT * WHERE A ="&C1:C10` instead of `"SELECT * WHERE A ="&C1&" OR A="&C2...`?

I might also use filters for this but I thought a Query might be easier

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Yes, it is possible - however, can you share a sample sheet with the current data and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a QUERY with regular expressions, something like:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select * where B matches 'India|Russia' ")
```

So this could be changed to perhaps this:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select * where A matches '"& TEXTJOIN("|",1,C1:C10) &"' ",0)
```